# Getting format on save to work with a default formatter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to set a default formatter for a specific workspace to Prettier and make format on save work nicely with each other. I tried this as follows:

[image]
[image]

(format on save is also enabled in the User settings)

For some reason, this is not working for me. If I manually run the format command via VS Code's command pallet, it formats using Prettier just fine.

Is there something I got wrong or another setting that needs configuring?

Comment: have you tried to reload the window after change of setting

Comment: @gftea Yes, I also tried completely restarting VS Code and my computer. None seemed to fix this issue.

Comment: Which file type are you using? there are some language/file specific settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if in your settings.json file, `{ "editor.formatOnSave": false }` is set to False, if yes, set it to `true`, I don't know why, but this value could still be set to false, even if both your above settings are turned on.

check:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "prettier.configPath": "./personal.yml"
}
```

if not, update the editor.defaultForamatter here to the shown value

Also, in your Editor:Default Formatter to `None`. Note that this is an alternative method (if above doesn't work)

Scroll down to check if formatter if enabled(checked) for all your languages

If this too doesn't work, one can always try rolling to a different version.
Or as a last resort, you can try uninstalling and installing vscode

Comment: Okay so a complete reinstall of VS Code did the trick..

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Format Document (in pop-up bar)
3. Select `Format Document`
4. Select `Configure Default Formatter...`
5. Select `Prettier - Code formatter`

Done!

Comment: This works, but I want this to be automated on every save.